# Laravel Eloquent - Multiple WHERE IN clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Is there any way of translating following query(only the WHERE IN clause)

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (first, second) IN ((1,2),(2,3))`

to Laravel Eloquent syntax?

I have tried passing an array as a first argument of `Table::whereIn()`, but somewhere in the process(Illuminate\Database\Grammar:58) it gets passed to `strtolower()` which does not accept an array.

Is there a workaround? Maybe something involving `whereInExistingQuery` method?

If there isn't, do you know how to go about implementing such feature?

**CLARIFICATION**: 
previously mentioned clause means that `(first = 1 AND second = 2) OR (first = 2 AND second = 3)`. Of course I can do this in nested queries `foreach`ing over all pairs but I was hoping for more elegant/straightforward solution.

**UPDATE**:
Because this query is invalid in eg. MSSQL, Oracle or sqlite, the only solution is to filter through columns and values:

```
$columns = ['first', 'second'];
$values = [
    [
        'first' => 1,
        'second' => 2
    ],
    [
        'first' => 2,
        'second' => 3,
    ]
];
Table::where(function($query) use ($columns, $values) {
    foreach ($values as $valueArray) {
        $query->orWhere(function($innerQuery) use ($columns, $valueArray) {
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                $innerQuery->where($column, '=', $valueArray[$column]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Write out a valid SQL query for your question.  Do not leave anything up to guessing so as to not waste people's time.

Comment: I'm sorry I mislead you. What do you mean `a valid SQL query`? Is this invalid in some sql dialects? I have tested this query in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Never mind.  Your update clearly expresses the logic you want in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The query is not "invalid" if you can write it.  If your paraphrased `WHERE` clause be accurate, then I see no problem.